# How to prevent an unintended resume from suspend (Lenovo x240)?

Tags: laptop, suspend, lenovo, lid

*Updated 2015-04-19, 15:56 - I am using a Lenovo x240 notebook and the problem is valid for Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 at least.*

### General description of the problem

If I close the notebook's lid, the system will be put into suspend mode (usually suspend to ram). However I notice an unintended resume from this suspend mode very often.

It happens while carrying the notebook in a bag as well as without any movement when the notebook stands on my desk for hours.

I am wondering that there is no question like this already.

Do you have any idea how to tell Ubuntu that if and only if the lid opens it should resume from suspend mode?

### Investigation that has be done so far

I started to investigate this issue. This is what happened when the described problem appears:

- 2015-04-18 - 18:21 - Lid closed and laptop put into a sideboard. The
  LED shows that suspend was successful. (slow blinking)
- 2015-04.18 - 21:01 - Syslog activity... System wakes up
- 2015-04-19 - 10:00 - Last entry in syslog 2015-04-19 - 15:00 - I picked the laptop from the sideboard. Battery is completely empty. (no LED light at all)

[This is the content of the /var/log/pm-suspend.log](http://pastebin.com/ZmBuFEx0) of the relevant time.

This is how the battery graph (of the main battery) looks like:

[image: Battery graph]

### Some additional information that might be useful

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup 
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID       S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
IGBE      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP2      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
```

Comment: Could it be that your lid doesn't close well and moving it opens it even slightly?

Comment: Not really. I can not provoke this behaviour by shaking the notebook or pressing at different parts of the lid or doing whatever.

Comment: Hmm. This is going to be hard to debug from a distance. Once thing you should do is have a look at `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` which logs the suspend/wake events. That will probably not contain the trigger but it might have something relevant. I suggest including the transcript for one of the suspend/resume cycles you describe (assuming you can identify it)  into you question.

Comment: It seems like the lid-closed sensor on your laptop is a little iffy. You may want to look into getting that fixed.

Comment: @terdon: I'll provide an excerpt from `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` as soon as it happens the next time. In addition I could disable the wake up for the lid in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` that currently cotains the following:
    Device S-state   Status   Sysfs node
    LID   S4 *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
    SLPB   S3 *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
    IGBE   S4 *disabled  pci:0000:00:19.0
    EXP2   S4 *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
    XHCI   S3 *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
    EHC1   S3 *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I installed Ubuntu 15.94 from scratch and do not have any problems.**

It seems there was something configured or installed before that caused the problem. However as it seem not to be an issue to many people I consider it as solved (unreproducible). If the problem happens again I will add information to the question and mark this answer not as solved any longer.